# Json object to return the result of total and name(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json

I have this Json Object, The idea is to match the id in the totalById and the nameById and return the value in this form

```
{
  name: Beginning,
  total: 20
}, {
  name: Automation,
  total: 0
}
attrs: {
  daily: {
    "totalById": {
      "6137ad545fc0c40785920e48": 0,
      "612e64f65fc0c4078569bacf": 0,
      "614231535fc0c40785bf0907": 20
    }
  },
  "nameById": {
    "6137ad545fc0c40785920e48": "Automation",
    "612e64f65fc0c4078569bacf": "Excellent Idea",
    "614231535fc0c40785bf0907": "Beginning ",
  }
}
```

I have tried ensuring that both of the object literals are in order and then use the object. Values () on each of the Object literals,

But I just cannot seem to get it to return in this form

{name: Beginning, total: 20}, {name: Automation, total: 0}

Comment: This is not valid JSON. If it's an array of objects, you need `[]` around it. But you can't have `attrs:` in an array.

Comment: Run that through: https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser . Also, please post the JavaScript you tried to use and failed with, and we'll fix it.